# can start-stop-daemon only run as su

Tags: ubuntu, cron, startup

Ubuntu Lucid.

I am writing a start/stop script for a program. The program shall be started/stopped by the crontab.

Running it as program-user, error message: start-stop-daemon command not found.
However, if I try it with sudo start-stop-daemon, it works.

Is there a way to get it to work running on program-user crontab?

Comment: Does the program-user have /sbin in its PATH? What happens if you explicitly call /sbin/start-stop-daemon?

Comment: /sbin/start-stop-daemon works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`start-stop-daemon` is in `/sbin` which is often not included in a user's `PATH`. It's also probably not in the default `PATH` for `cron`. You can add it for a particular user in their `~/.bashrc` or for all users in `/etc/bash.bashrc`. If you're starting it in a `crontab` or in a script run from a `crontab`, just add the full path like this: `/sbin/start-stop-daemon ...`.